# SQL Server CE and C#; Populate a DataSet with ALL the Tables from a SQL Server CE DB

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, sql-server-ce

How would I Populate a DataSet with ALL the Tables from a SQL Server CE database. Is this possible in ONE SQL select statement?

I know that I can call separate select statements with the names of the table I need data from but I need a generic solution that just dumps all the tables from the SQL Server CE database into a Dataset.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

1. Run it to get all the queries.
2. Run each query, dumping it in the same dataset.

This works very easy.

Edit: I think I also had problems trying to run multiple queries in a single go with SQL CE (even with the line terminator `;`).

Comment: THANKS! That was quick. Interesting Solution